# How to cancel the binding of option key in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that OXS bind special keys on option key, such as option+y=¥,option+t=þ... But now, I want to cancel all these bindings, and use option+character as the shortcuts in JetBrains IDEs and other apps.
I have searched for hours and still haven't found a useful way.Can anyone share a tool or the correct way?I used the way to add `Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file, but it only canceled some key-bindings, not work for all.
It is my DefaultKeyBinding.dict file below :

```
{
"~d" = "deleteWordForward:";
"^w" = "deleteWordBackward:";
"~f" = "moveWordForward:";
"~b" = "moveWordBackward:";
"~u" = "pageUp:";
}
```

Now ,option+f/b can used as my jetbrains IDEs shortcut,but option+u still print special character.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way: if I select `Unicode Hex Input` as my input source from `System preferences->keyBoard->Input Sources`, all bindings now disappeared!